# Finding solutions to a linear system in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an equation like this

```
 y = a*x+b;
```

I have sets of `y` and `x`

```
 y = [1 2 3 4 5]
 x = [6 7 8 9 10]
```

I want to find `a` and `b`, but not one solution; all solutions. I guess, I have to use `polyfit`, but I don't know how to do this and I don't understand *why* I have to use `polyfit`? Can you explain this to me?

Comment: There is only one solution to this problem:
a = 1
b = -5

Comment: @onewhaleid It’s probably an example.

Comment: yes it is only example i need solution sets. for a and for b.

Comment: @Lumen yes, but the question doesn't make sense to me. The OP has given a single linear equation, of which there can be only one solution. `polyfit` will work, but it will only give one solution.

Comment: @legelstein are you just asking how polyfit works?

Comment: actually i have x and y such that doesn't give me one solution, many solutions,

Comment: @David yes , but i dont know how to implement this in matlab.

Comment: See my answer, have you read the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

From the [polyfit documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html):

> `p = polyfit(x,y,n)` finds the coefficients of a polynomial `p(x)` of
>   degree n that fits the data, `p(x(i))` to `y(i)`, in a least squares
>   sense. The result `p` is a row vector of length `n+1` containing the
>   polynomial coefficients in descending powers:

So, you have data `y` at x-coordinates `x`, and you want to fit a first-degree polynomial to it. So use

```
p=polyfit(x,y,1);
```

and then `p(1)=a` and `p(2)=b`, or `y=p(1)*x+p(2)`.

There are other ways to do this, but `polyfit` is very simple.

Comment: But does `polyfit` return "all solutions? As it's based on least squares, I'm guessing that it just returns one solution.

Comment: I think OP has multiple sets of x and y to solve for. As it's based on least squares, it should return the solution with the least error. I can't think that there could be multiple solutions with the same error?